# tabbarcontoller tab to the popviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

In my app tabbar contain four tab on 
first tab button is their on clicking on that button 
it should jump to second tab i haved used.

```
   self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

it works but requirement is that 
on clicking on that button it should pop

to the first viewcontroller of second tab.

thank in advanced

Comment: what do you mean by first viewcontroller? can you please elaborate?

Comment: mean in second tab contain navigationcontroller - viewcontroller1-viewcontroller2 so i want to go to viewcontroller1

Comment: @PratyushaTerli He want to poptorootviewcontroller on selecting the second tab bar

Answer (score 0):

You can check this when going to second tab bar in you appdelegate delegate method is called here you can poptorootviewcontroller

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Put following code inside this delegate method.

```
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) 
{
   [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it working i haved used below code. on button click

```
 self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;


        [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```